# How can I Automate Orient Db Backups?

Tags: orientdb

I want to schedule my `orient db` backups. Can i do it using HTTP api? Or any other methods? Please advice me to do this.
Thank you.

Comment: What version are you using ?
Have you already looked at the official documentation http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Automatic-Backup.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alessandro already mentioned, you can use the [Automatic Backup plugin](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Automatic-Backup.html) or even better the Incremental Non-Stop Backup available in the [Enterprise Edition](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Studio-Backup-Management.html).

Comment: I have tried automatic backups. i have changed the orientdb-server-config.xml as follows.

Comment: I have tried automatic backups. i have changed the `orientdb-server-config.xml` as follows.but it is not working.